# In puppeteer, how do you intercept a redirect after window.open?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, web-scraping, puppeteer

Let's say there is a website with the following content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const onClick = async (event) => {
    var page = window.open('', '_blank');
    var url = await someCrypticFunctionality();
    page.location.replace(url);
  }
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="onClick">Click here</button>
```

Using puppeteer I want to visit the page, click the button (so far so good) and then retrieve the `url`, preferably before requesting whatever is located at that URL. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `this.request.isNavigationRequest` is more suited to your case. but you might want to combine `.redirectChain().legnth` and `isNavigationRequest` since you don't want to block the very first navigation to the page itself

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on("request", async request => {
  if (request.isNavigationRequest() && request.redirectChain().length > 0) {
    await request.abort();
  }
});
```

Comment: Made an edit again. I think this.request.isNavigationRequest is more suited to your case

Comment: Its works. I'm not sure why you created this whole class around it to be honest, but it works and that's what counts :)

Comment: It's my style. I assumed you have more things you will add to your request interceptor. I group similar operations that all happens on the request object in a class with the requester as dependency in the constructor.
Ignore that if you only write standalone functions